# Pass JWT token from angular HttpClient to access secure .NET Core Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, angular9, .net-core-3.1, .net-core-authorization

I need to call secure Web API from Angular 9 application by presenting the token. I am using Angular with .NET CORE 3.1 Web API. I have managed to generate Azure B2C token but stuck to call secure web api as I got CORS error.

### Angular component calling Web API end-point

```
testAPI1(){
    console.log("calling test API ...");

    const myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': this.authService.accessToken
    });

    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/txn/v1/Dashboard/GetMessage', {headers: myheaders})
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            console.warn(data);
        })
}
```

### Auth Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit{

constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router

){// other code}


public get accessToken() { 
    return this.oauthService.getAccessToken(); 
}
```

### Web API controller & endpoint

```
[Authorize]
[Route("txn/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[ApiController]
public class DashboardController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<HelloMessage> GetMessage()
    {
        var result = new HelloMessage()
        {
            GivenName = "james",
            ReturnMessage = "Dashboard@ Hello, Welcome to Digital tech"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       //JWT Authentication 
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtConfig => 
            {
                jwtConfig.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ResourceId"];
                jwtConfig.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TanantId"]}";
                jwtConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jwtConfig.SaveToken = true;
                jwtConfig.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer =true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true

                };
        });

 //CORS policy
 services.AddCors(options =>
                          options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));
```

### error

[image]

Comment: `got CORS error` Please share the detailed error message, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better. Besides, configuring with both *AllowAnyOrigin* and *AllowCredentials* methods is not recommended. You can try to specify the allowed origins using *WithOrigins* method.

Comment: I have update question with error and also paste JWT authentication method, not sure if I did mistake there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Policies for CORS can be a bit finicky. So I would recommend maybe trying for a pretty open CORS policy (Which isn't too dangerous given you are using header authentication and not a cookie).

So your configure services method should look like so :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

And then your Configure method should be something like :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors( options => options.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod() );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Note that the order inside the Configure method is important. The call to CORS *must* be relatively early on, if not the first middleware in your pipeline.

If that works, then work backwards to slowly add policies and see which one breaks. CORS can be really finicky so it works better to allow everything in a basic example and then add thing slowly in.

More reading here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/03/enabling-cors-asp-net-core/

Comment: I have tried as you have suggested but getting no luck, is throwing following error that I have upload in question at bottom

Comment: And when you call this API directly (Postman, In your browser etc), and check the headers, you can see it's returning the CORS headers that you expect? Because it's saying that it's not returning Access-Control-Origin which means CORS is not set up correctly.

Comment: I have to change the CORS as following and managed to run and call Web API but getting 401 unauthorized error 

services.AddCors(options =>
                                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                                {
                                    builder
                                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        ;
                                }));